# Read EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME in Safari via Javascript for an HLS stream

Tags: safari, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I have a video stream that has `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` successfully embedded in the .m3u8 file. This stream plays natively on Safari, but I'm unable to find a way to access the value from Javascript (or at all really). Does anyone have an idea of how to get this value from the stream so I can correlate it with the currently playing video?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pull the `.m3u8` file via a separate [`fetch`](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or `xhr` request, then parse the contents as text. You can use a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/m3u8-parser) to do it, or just use a RegExp (`/#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME\s*:\s*([\d-T:.-Z]+)/`)

Comment: But how would I receive the updated versions of the `.m3u8` as the stream continues playing? The stream might stutter and things would get out of sync if I use the original `.m3u8`

Comment: Your original ask didn't mention anything about the program date time changing. You can keep polling the m3u8 file (be sure to set request to 'no-cache'). Or stand on the shoulders of giants and use a library like [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) or [video.js](https://videojs.com/).

Comment: Sorry, when I talked about the .m3u8 file, I meant the initial m3u8 along with the one that is downloaded periodically while streaming. I am using video.js (and I've looked into hls.js) but both of them still require me to use the native streaming on safari and ios.